# How do I set the center of rotation of a Qt3D scene to the center of the active .obj file in the scene?

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, qt3d

I have a Qt3D scene in which I have only one 3D object. I would like to set the center of rotation of the scene(camera) to the center of this 3D object. Currently, the 3D model goes out of view when the scene is rotated with the mouse.

Comment: One quick idea that is a bit hacky is to not allow the camera to actually rotate but instead catch the mouse events and set the rotation on the object by a delta when the mouse moves.

Comment: thanks for that I will give it a try. however, I am just wondering if this abnormal behaviour is how the FirstPersonCameraController { camera: camera } is supposed to be

Answer (score 1):

There is also a OrbitCameraController, which has the purpose to look at a certain position. You could let the camera position track your object's position.

QML example code:

```
Camera {
    id: myCamera
    viewCenter: YOUROBJECTPOSITION
}

OrbitCameraController { camera: myCamera }
// FirstPersonCameraController { camera: myCamera }
```

I'm not using pyqt like you do. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am using a Mesh with a custom 3D model as "source" the qt docs don't really indicate any property of the Mesh object that will return its 3Dvector position.

Comment: Can you tell more about your custom 3D model? Some code would be helpfull.

Comment: @eyllanesc Can u help me for this https://forum.qt.io/topic/122065/how-to-rotate-object-in-3d-space-about-its-axis

Answer (score 0):

> I am using a Mesh with a custom 3D model as "source" the qt docs don't
>   really indicate any property of the Mesh object that will return its
>   3Dvector position.

If you import your obj file in a scene the origin of your mesh is placed at the origin of the scene. If you didn't transform it that origin is where you want the camera to look at.

If you used a transform, then use that new position to look at.

Qt3D uses an ECS (Entitiy Component System) Basically, you make an enitity and add components to it like a mesh and transform in your case. That's why the mesh doesn't have a property that reflects it's position. The transform component holds that information.

I suggest you read the following in the Qt docs: [Qt3D Architecture](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt3d-overview.html#qt-3d-architecture)

The above solution is just in case you have smaller objects and your camera is far enough. But if you import a larger mesh fi. like a spaceship you might need to get the coordinates of the spot you want to look at. You can get those coordinates by using an object picker.